# Pandas - I have a dataset where the clmns r country, company and total employees. I need a dataframe for total employees in each company by country

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There are totally 8 companies and around 30 - 40 countries. I need to get a dataframe where i can know how many total number of employees in each company by country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use Panda's groupby feature.  I'm not sure what type of data you have and what result you want, so here are some toy examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ["A", "A", "B"], 'country': ["USA", "USA", "USA"], 'employees': [10, 20, 50]})
dfg = df.groupby(['company', 'country'], as_index=False)['employees'].sum()

print(dfg)
#   company country  employees
# 0       A     USA         30
# 1       B     USA         50

df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ["A", "A", "A"], 'country': ["USA", "USA", "Japan"], 'employees': ['Art', 'Bob', 'Chris']})
dfg = df.groupby(['company', 'country'], as_index=False)['employees'].count()

print(dfg)
#   company country  employees
# 0       A   Japan          1
# 1       A     USA          2
```

Comment: how do i get percentages of employees for each country?

Comment: If you accept my answer and let me know if you want, I can write the code.  Do you want:  for each company, for each country where the company has employees, what percentage of that company's employees are in each of the countries?

Comment: I did accept your answer. Thanks ! Actually i need another help. I will post another question if you can help me with another data set. Thanks again

Comment: @Akira, thanks, and I'll be happy to look at your next question

Comment: Were u able to look at my next question?

Comment: @Hammurabhi herr is the link to my next question.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/68416533/16458720

Comment: Looks like someone posted a good answer to that question.  If you need help with it, just let me know.

Comment: hi yes someone did answer but that looks like more complex and also i dont think they answered my first question which is the percentages one. Can u please help me with it?